# SaltStack state issue with file salt.states.file.copy

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to merge a folder with files in source location to a folder with files in destination location
and instead of just copying files / overwriting, salt just wipes out the destination

```
  file.copy:
    - name: D://
    - source: D://Staged/Folder
    - force: True
    - makedirs: True
    - subdir: True
    - preserve: True
```

So I am trying to copy folders/files from D://Staged/Folder to D://Folder (D://Folder already exists with folders and files)
Instead everything inside D://Folder gets wiped out

Comment: Why do you have `force: True`, if you don't want to overwrite the destination?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to copy files from the source directory to destination irrespective of its existence and contents.

Since you are using a "state" module, it will try to match the state of your destination path to the one given in source. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943937/saltstack-modules-vs-states) for example on difference between state and execution modules.

You could instead use the `file.copy` [execution module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html) for this purpose:

```yaml
copy_files:
  module.run:
    - file.copy:
        - src: D:/Staged/Folder
        - dst: D:/Folder
        - recurse: True
```

As with an execution module, this will run every time. Even if the source and destination directories have the same contents.